# Split list of strings on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, text

I have a number of sentences which I would like to split on specific words (e.g. and). However, when splitting the sentences sometimes there are two or more combinations of a word I'd like to split on in a sentence.

Example sentences:

```
['i', 'am', 'just', 'hoping', 'for', 'strength', 'and', 'guidance', 'because', 'i', 'have', 'no', 'idea', 'why']
['maybe', 'that', 'is', 'why', 'he', 'does', 'not', 'come', 'home', 'and', 'tell', 'you', 'how', 'good', 'his', 'day', 'at', 'work', 'was', 'because', 'he', 'is', 'been', 'told', 'not', 'to', 'talk']
```

so I have written some code to split a sentence:

```
split_on_word = []
no_splitting = []
indexPosList = [ i for i in range(len(kth)) if kth[i] == 'and'] # check if word is in sentence
for e in example: 
  kth = e.split() # split strings into list so it looks like example sentence
  for n in indexPosList:
    if n > 4: # only split when the word's position is 4 or more 
      h = e.split("and")
      for i in h: 
        split_on_word.append(i)# append split sentences 
    else:
      no_splitting.append(kth) #append sentences that don't need to be split
```

However, you can see that when using this code more than once (e.g.: replace the word to split on with another) I will create duplicates or part duplicates of the sentences that I append to a new list.

Is there any way to check for multiple conditions, so that if a sentence contains both or other combinations of it that I split the sentence in one go?

The output from the examples should then look like this:

```
['i', 'am', 'just', 'hoping', 'for', 'strength']
['guidance', 'because']
['i', 'have', 'no', 'idea', 'why']

['maybe', 'that', 'is', 'why', 'he', 'does', 'not', 'come', 'home']
[ 'tell', 'you', 'how', 'good', 'his', 'day', 'at', 'work', 'was']
['he', 'is', 'been', 'told', 'not', 'to', 'talk']
```

Comment: you have 2 lists of words, that are your sentences already split intro words?

Comment: @kederrac yes so I only want to split the sentences if the index position of the word I want to split on is after position 4, otherwise the sentence is just appended.

Comment: @kederrac are you referring to the two lists that are under "example sentences"?

Comment: also, please add `kth` and `e` variables

Comment: @kederrac these are two separate example sentences, I updated the output to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a function that checks whether a word is a split-word:

```
In [11]: split_words = {'and', 'because'}                                                     

In [12]: [list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(example, key=lambda x: x not in split_words) if k]   
Out[12]: 
[['maybe', 'that', 'is', 'why', 'he', 'does', 'not', 'come', 'home'],
 ['tell', 'you', 'how', 'good', 'his', 'day', 'at', 'work', 'was'],
 ['he', 'is', 'been', 'told', 'not', 'to', 'talk']]
```